# What's the fastest way to tear apart Koloktos' heart?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

When fighting [Koloktos](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14-skyward-sword-bosses.php#Koloktos), after breaking the cage that covers his chest, should I keep using his giant ali baba sword to slash at his heart, or is it faster to drop it and use my own?

I only get about 2 good swings with the giant one, and I could probably get 5 or 6 in at least with my own, but I'm not sure if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any numerical data, but I think the large sword does way more damage than your own. I remember going through five or six phases of slashing with the Goddess Sword without killing him, while with the scimitars it takes only two or three.